# Create triangle that do not change angle in css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm fairly new in react and also in css in general and i'm wondering how i could create a background triangle for my app that take full width bug do not change angle as the page is resized.

This is my actual page :[image: Page with the triangle in the background]

And this is the css that come with it :

```
  diagonaleBottom: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    width: "100%",
    height: "35%",
    clipPath: "polygon(100% 100%, 0 100%, 100% 0)",
    background: "#082333",
    zIndex: 1,
  },
```

The CSS syntax is not a standard one as i'm using js-css but if you give me an answer with some regular css it fine for me.

And my issue is that as my page skrink down my background triangle become more like this:

[image]

Does someone know if there is a way to maintain the same angle of my triangle as the page skrink down and like the overflow hide away as the page is skrinking ?
Ps : I already  tried to use `overflow:"hidden"` but it didn't change anything

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a gradient with a fixed size like below:

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,white 50%,blue 50%) bottom left/5000px 5000px;
}
```

I considered height=width so you will have 45deg. adjust it to get the angle you want.

Another example:

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,white 50%,blue 50%) bottom left/5000px 3000px;
}
```

You can also change the position if you want to make it fixed on the top right

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,white 50%,blue 50%) top right/5000px 3000px;
}
```

Comment: as I use your idea my background shape just disapear. Do you have an idea why it is happening  ?

Comment: @MichelMelhem I need to see how you are applying my idea

Comment: @MichelMelhem you removed the width:100%, you need to keep it

Comment: It seem to work fine but as i go to mobile the triangle split in half like the top stay at the bottom of the page and the bottom of the triangle go to the top of the page. If my explanations are not clear i will post a srceenshot

Comment: @MichelMelhem share screenshot here in comment, not in the question

Comment: @MichelMelhem I don't see any issue, this is the logical result of keeping the same angle and position it at the bottom left. If you want to change the position consider my last example

Comment: I realize i posted the two wrong screenshots now the second one show the top

Comment: @MichelMelhem for your last screenshot you have an issue somewhere else because I can see that the element isn't full height of the screen. Instead of using your position:absolute element, consider my exact code where you apply the gradient to the html element

Comment: @MichelMelhem so remove your position:absolute and simply add my code

Comment: If i remove the position absolute the triangle is not drawn anymore @Temani Afif

Comment: @MichelMelhem I didn't say only remove the position absolute. I said remove the *element* and use my code where I am applying the background to the html element and I as you can see it works fine

Answer (score 2):

A [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) could accomplish this:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(-30deg, tomato 50%, bisque 50%);
}
```

Comment: as I use your idea my background shape just disapear. Do you have an idea why it is happening ?

Comment: Without seeing your code my guess is that the element containing the gradient has 0 height.